# Approximation of an infinite series using an integral.

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

For electric potential I have the following infinite series:

$V=k_e\frac{q}{r}+2k_eq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+n^2a^2}}$

Taking the derivative with respect to r, I have the following infinite series for electric field:

$E_r=k_eq\frac{1}{r^2}+k_eq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(r^2+n^2a^2)^{-3/2}2r$

I am trying to approximate the sum as an integral to show that, as $r$ gets very large, the electric field approaches the field due to a line charge $E=2k_e\frac{\lambda}{r}$, but I am having trouble getting this result.  What I get is:

$E_r=k_eq\frac{1}{r^2}+k_eq\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{t}(r^2+r^2a^2)^{-3/2}2rdr$

ignoring the first term because it will go away when taking the limit as $r$ gets large,

$E_r=2(1+a^2)k_eq\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1}^{t}r^{-2}dr$

so,

$E_r=2(1+a^2)^{-3/2}k_eq$.

I keep getting this result and am not sure where my mistake is. Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you define $\lambda$ in terms of $a$ and $q$?

Comment: $\lambda=\frac{q}{a}$

Comment: Well, if you are sending $r \to \infty$ then your answer will never contain r, so you're fighting a losing battle there. You need to show something like $\lim_{r\to\infty} \frac{E_r}{k_e\frac{\lambda}{r}} = 1$

Comment: Right - indeed, you changed the discrete variable $n$ to a continuous variable (totally fine) - but you called that continuous variable $r$, which already appears in the formula. That's why $r$ disappeared at the end.